# Dual-boot windows 7 and Antergos Linux. Windows will only boot some times

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, grub, arch-linux

Not long ago i clean installed windows 7 on ,y laptop. I then installed Antergos for dual-booting. Then windows chould not boot so i used boot-repair to fix it. When i now go in to grub to boot windows 7, I usualy get a blue/purple screen full of horizontal lines and it gets stuck there. But some times, when have not tried in a while, it randomly boots in to windows when i select it in grub (Antergos boots just fine btw).

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Create Windows Repair/Installation DVD/USB.
2. Repair Windows 7 booting using media from step 1.
3. Reinstall GRUB from DVD/USB.

If you need further help for any step I could supply links and/or explanations.